# How to get the value of redux store in other components on typescript react hooks project

Tags: reactjs, typescript, redux, react-router

a gopher new come to react. Now i write a easy example with golang and React.ts. the server will return a tokenstring, the `Login components` will receive the token string and decode it get a `UserState` interface type variable,

```js
export interface UserState {
  name: string;
  role: string;
}
```

then send a dispatch with this `user`.  Now I want print the current user name on Home Component.I try the `store.getState()` function, but i don't know how to defines the type of  `Home component` params..So what is the best way to get the user name on `store` in Home Component? Thanks!

This is `Login Compoent` file the `...` means `return block` that just a form with two inputs and a submit button.Now I want get the user name

```js
const Login: React.FC<RouteComponentProps> = (props: RouteComponentProps) => {
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);
  const antIcon = <LoadingOutlined style={{ fontSize: 24 }} spin />;
  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  const handleSubmit = async (values: LoginFormData) => {
    try {
      setLoading(true);
      const result = (await request(
        '/api/login',
        values,
        'POST'
      )) as LoginResponseData;
      if (result.code === '1') {
        storageUtils.saveToken(result.token);
        const user = storageUtils.getUser(result.token);
        dispatch(receiveUser(user));
        message.success(result.msg);
        setLoading(false);
        props.history.push('/home');
      } else {
        message.error(result.msg);
        setLoading(false);
      }
    } catch (err) {
      message.error(err.message);
    }
  };
.... 
export default Login;
```

These is my redux define.`actions.ts`

```js
import storageUtils from '../utils/storage';
import { UserState } from '../types/global';

export const RECEIVE_USER = 'receive_user';
export const RESET_USER = 'reset_user';

interface ReceiveUser {
  type: typeof RECEIVE_USER;
  payload: UserState;
}

interface LogOut {
  type: typeof RESET_USER;
}

export type UserAction = ReceiveUser | LogOut;

export const receiveUser = (user: UserState) => ({
  type: RECEIVE_USER,
  payload: user,
});

export const logout = () => {
  storageUtils.removeToken();
  return { type: RESET_USER };
};
```

The reducer

```js
import { combineReducers } from 'redux';
import { RECEIVE_USER, RESET_USER, UserAction } from './action';
import { UserState } from '../types/global';

const initialUser: UserState = { name: '', role: '' };

function user(state = initialUser, action: UserAction) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case RECEIVE_USER:
      return { ...state, ...action.payload };
    case RESET_USER:
      return {};
    default:
      return state;
  }
}

export default combineReducers({
  user,
});
```

My store.

```js
import { createStore } from 'redux';
import rootReducer from './reducer';

const initialState = {};

const store = createStore(rootReducer, initialState);

export default store;
```

I use the `<Provider store={store}> <Router/> </Provider>` tag nested the `Router` compoent.
my `Router` compoent

```js
const Login = React.lazy(() => import('./../views/login'));

const Routers: React.FC = () => (
  <HashRouter>
    <Suspense fallback={<Loading />}>
      <Switch>
        <Route exact path="/" component={Login} />
        <Route path="/home" component={Home} />
      </Switch>
    </Suspense>
  </HashRouter>
);

export default Routers;
```

A easy Home compoent.

```js
const Home: React.FC = () => {
  return <div>The current user name is {user.name}</div>;
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the username from a function component by using `useSelector`

ref: https://react-redux.js.org/api/hooks#useselector

Something like this:

```
const username = useSelector(state => state.user.username)
```

Wherever possible, try to use this `useSelector` method, because it highly optimizes the state selector, and you can even create custom functions that return the same specific field for reusability.

Comment: Thanks ,finally  i got the value.